# Regex to validate ascending and decending number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to put restriction on setting login pin which should **not accept ascending** order eg. 123456789 etc **but accept 1256...** and also should **not accept descending order** eg. 987654321 etc **but accept 9865 etc**  max 4-6 digit are allowed.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not a thing you should use regex for in the first place.

Comment: if(["123456789", "987654321"].includes(digit)) alert(" no thats to easy");

Comment: @CBroe than what to use to get this condition true

Comment: How about checking whether the pin in its entirety is a substring of 123456789 or 987654321?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex you could use a simple validator like this one:

```js
function checkPIN(str) {
  return "123456789".indexOf(str) === -1 && "987654321".indexOf(str) === -1 && str.length > 3 && str.length < 7
}

console.log(checkPIN("1234"))
console.log(checkPIN("12345"))
console.log(checkPIN("1245"))
```